# React: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, error-handling, render

Can Anyone help me please. Basically I am using React with Typescript for a project for school and all of a sudden this error happens and I don't understand why... I tried solving it with a boolean state and a simple Work[], two states and it always spits out the same error: Too many re-renders and I can't imagine why. To the kind soul that saves me, you have my thanks

This is my component

```
export default function WorkList(props :any) {
   const id = props.id
   const [works, setWorks] = useState<Work[]>()

    useEffect(()=> {
        if(!works){
            Api.fetchFromAPI(
                HTTP_METHOD.GET,
                `/artist/${id}/worksofart?token=${AuthService.getToken()}`,
                new Headers()
            ).then((listOfWorks) => {
                setWorks(listOfWorks)
            })
        }
    }, [works])

    function renderWorks(work: Work) {
        return <WorkPost work={work}/>
    }

    return !works ? (
        <div>
            <h3>Loading works...</h3>
        </div>
    ) : (
        <div className={"work-panel"}>
            <h3>Works Of Art:</h3>
            <div>
                {works.map(renderWorks)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is my work object

```
export class Work {
    public id: string;
    public work_name: string;
    public owner: string;
    public description: string;
    public reviews: number;
    public tags: Array<string>
    public content: string
    public fileExtension: string
    public comments: Array<string>;
    public ups: Array<string>;

    constructor(id: string, work_name: string, owner: string, description: string, reviews: number, tags: Array<string>, content: string, fileExtension: string, commments: Array<string>, ups: Array<string>) {
        this.id = id
        this.work_name = work_name
        this.owner = owner
        this.description = description
        this.reviews = reviews
        this.tags = tags
        this.content = content
        this.fileExtension = fileExtension
        this.comments = commments
        this.ups = ups
    }

}
```

My current thought on it is that my works array is very large and as a consequence takes a while to finish the setWorks and as it hasn't finished yet, it renders again and again and again. I might be absolutely wrong...

The output is this: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGsHZ.png)
[Error Output - Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKoOg.png)

UPDATE: The error was in the `WorkPost` component and not here, even tho it said it was here. I had a state that was updating without control or review so it was rendering, updating, rendering, etc.
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Here's your code in an example where the network IO has been removed and replaced with something more predicable... https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-wildflower-stxeo?file=/src/App.tsx . Seems to work fine...

Comment: ...which leads to the next question.... are you 100% sure that this is the problematic code?

Answer (score 0):

Too many re-renders means you have an infinite loop somewhere. What I would do is: add a default value for works =>

```
const [works, setWorks] = useState<Work[]>([])
```

Can you also check the listOfWorks response? Because this could be empty, change the reference of work, retrigger the useEffect callback and start the infinite loop.

Why is it needed to have works as dependency in the useEffect? You could remove this, have an empty list as dependency and have this code run once, after mount.

```
useEffect(()=> {
        if(!works.length){
            Api.fetchFromAPI(
                HTTP_METHOD.GET,
                `/artist/${id}/worksofart?token=${AuthService.getToken()}`,
                new Headers()
            ).then((listOfWorks) => {
                setWorks(listOfWorks)
            })
        }
    }, [])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The listOfWorks has the content that it should.

Comment: You should also set a key={work.id} at renderWorks

Comment: I tried both adding a default value to the works state and removing the dependencies from useEffect and none of that worked, it's still givving me the same error.

Comment: why that key? To what purpose?

Comment: For the key: you should add a key to a list (.map) to let React know what to re-render and when: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured out it was on my WorkPost Component and not on this one, even tho the error explicitly said it was here. I had a set on a state without checking anything and was doing it infinite times...